Different Hodge numbers arising from different holomorphic structures?
Does anyone have an example or know any references for a complex manifold $M$ with two different holomorphic structures that give rise to different Hodge numbers?

pleasantpheasant -- how do you define the Hodge numbers in the non-K"ahler case?

algori - The dimension of the Dolbeault cohomology groups on M

In a complex manifold the holomorphic structure is fixed. You probably mean "a smooth manifold $M$ with two different complex structures"?

A well-studied example is given by the Iwasawa manifold, see 1.4.3 in Angella's thesis here https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0524.
